# Copying files in Linux from Windows

Tags: linux, transfer

I am trying to copy files from a GNU/Linux host to a windows host. The windows host is inside a firewall and Linux host is outside the firewall.

I need to issue a command from Windows box that will copy files from Linux box.

Could any one let me know the possible ways to do it?

Comment: We need more information to answer this. Are the files on the same computer? (shared FAT32 folder, ex2fs driver for windows), are they on different hosts (scp would do nicely in that case), ....

Comment: you can also use services like Dropbox if you find WinSCP, Samba and other tools more complicated

Comment: Hi Hennes, The files are located in Unix box and I need to copy those files in to a windows box. Windows box is with in the firewall and Linux box out side the firewall. I am planning to create a command line interface that need to connect to the linux box and copy the files in to Windows box.

Answer (score 2):

See if there's a way to install [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) on your flavour of Linux. If there is, you will be able to access 'shared folder' on the Linux machine much like it were a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

as Hennes mentioned more info would be helpful.
If you insist on using a command line interface the built in ftp command could do the trick as long as your linux box allows for ftp access.
If you prefer a GUI tool, take a look at [WinSCP](http://winscp.net), same story with your linux box, it has to allow you in. WinSCP also can do FTP.

Comment: Hi , I need to create a command line interface that commincate the linux box from the windows box and copy the files from the linux box to the windows box.

Comment: If your linux box allows ftp-access you could use the ftp command line tool that comes with Windows. You can also use textfiles to hold your command sequences and run it using those. http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm  be aware though that ftp is rather insecure.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an Open Source project called [cross copy](http://www.cross-copy.net) to do exactly this kind of inter-device file transfer via web browser (and Smartphones btw).

1. Open http://www.cross-copy.net on both computers (on Linux you can also use the [command line client](https://github.com/rodja/cross-copy/blob/master/cmd-client/cross-copy)).
2. enter the same code word on both websites
3. start uploading files --- they will instantly appear on the other side for downloading

Answer (score -1):

I copy files from linux to windows (dual boot) using an application called ext2explore.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/Ext2Read%20ver%202.0/ext2explore%202.0%20beta/

Comment: I do not think this is what Sasidharan needed for their situation.

Comment: Agreed. But that was not clear from the original question.